# How many 3D shapes can be made from five cubes

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

How many different ways can five cubes be arranged such that at least one face is touching. For example, in the photo the top three show possible arrangements, but the bottom one is not allowed as the cubes are not connected.[image: cube images]

Answer (score 2):

These are called [*polycubes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycube).

With 5 cubes, there are 29 ways to join them, including six pairs that differ only by a mirror reflection. If you don't consider the mirror reflections as different, there are 23.